# Org mode tag column setting is ignored

Tags: org-mode, align, org-tags, doom

Running Doom Emacs v 2.0.9.

My `~/.doom.d/init.el` contains:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-tags-column -80)
)
```

When I add tags using `counsel-org-tag`, the tag alignment in the current headline is destroyed. When I try to realign them using `SPC-u C-C C-C`, all tags become left aligned!

When I `customize-variables` org-tag-column, it shows 'changed outside customize'. When I set up the value again and go back to the buffer to `SPC-u C-C C-C` all works as expected.

I thought with that setting in init.el, all these steps should be unnecessary.

How do I get the alignment behavior as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doom is meant to be configured via `~/.doom.d/config.el`. Try setting the `org-tags-column` in that file. E.g.:

```
;; in ~/.doom.d/config.el
(after! org
  (setq org-tags-column -80)
   ;; ... other org configuration here
)
```

You may need to restart emacs for these changes to be applied, and then `SPC-u C-c C-c` should properly align the tags.